# set polylines in googlemap from values in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have seen this link:

[Google map api v3 add polylines from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176349/google-map-api-v3-add-polylines-from-array)

this is somehow slightly the same as my problem.. you see, im getting a javscript error as such this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPath' of undefined 
AddCoordinate map:118
(anonymous function)
```

well my code is basically populating the coordinates first as the page is loaded together with the map.. And by the time that click is triggered (html button), that is the only time that the map will be plotted with poly lines.. I hope I explained it very well though.. Here's what i got:

```
    var map;
    var Markers = [];
    var Coordinates = [];
    var LinePath;

    function initialize()
    {  
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -140.821856);
      var myOptions = {
                zoom: 3,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
          };
      var MarkerSize = new google.maps.Size(48,48);
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    }

    function AddCoordinate( lat, long )                                                                                                                         {
      var path = LinePath.getPath(); 
      path.push( new google.maps.LatLng( lat, long ) );
      LinePath.setPath(path);
    }


    function PlotLine()
    {
      LinePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path:Coordinates,                                                                                                                           
                strokeColor:"#ffffff",
                strokeOpacity:1.0,
                strokeWeight:5
                });
      LinePath.setMap(map);
    }


   <html>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" ></div>
    <?php
                    foreach($arrayOfPlotPoints as $key => $value){ 
                        $longitude = round($value['longitude'],5);
                        $latitude = round($value['latitude'],5);
                        $snrLevel = $value['snr_level'];
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">AddCoordinate('.$latitude.','.$longitude.')</script>';
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $longitude.",".$latitude.",".$snrLevel?>"> Lg:<?php echo $longitude." Lt: ".$latitude." LV: ".$snrLevel?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                    <br /><br />
                    <?php echo $this->Form->button('PLOT', array('type'=>'button', 'onclick'=>'PlotLine()')); ?>
echo $this->Form->button('PLOT', array('type'=>'button', 'onclick'=>'PlotLine()')); 
     ?>
```

********EDITED**********

i have made a partial modification of my code.. however im getting the same error..

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPath' of undefined 
    AddCoordinate (anonymous function)


function initialize() {
 //.....
 LinePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path:Coordinates,                                                                                                                           //san ka galing Coordinates??? dineclare ka pero di ka aman nilagyan "YATA" ng laman
        strokeColor:"#ffffff",
        strokeOpacity:1.0,
        strokeWeight:5
        });
}


function AddCoordinate( latitude, longitude )                                                                                                                       {
  var path = LinePath.getPath(); 
  path.push(  latitude, longitude  );
}

function PlotLine()
{
  LinePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path:Coordinates,                                                                                                                           
            strokeColor:"#ffffff",
            strokeOpacity:1.0,
            strokeWeight:5
            });
  LinePath.setMap(map);

}

<HTML>
select name="long_and_lat" id="long_and_lat" style="width:220px;height:250px;" size="100">
                <?php    
                $plotPoints = array();
                foreach($arrayOfPlotPoints as $key => $value){ 
                    $longitude = round($value['longitude'],5);
                    $latitude = round($value['latitude'],5);
                    $snrLevel = $value['snr_level'];
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">AddCoordinate('.$latitude.','.$longitude.')</script>';
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $longitude.",".$latitude.",".$snrLevel?>"> Lg:<?php echo $longitude." Lt: ".$latitude." LV: ".$snrLevel?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <br /><br />
                <?php echo $this->Form->button('PLOT', array('type'=>'button', 'onclick'=>'PlotLine()')); ?>
</html>
```

Comment: i found my prob... i confirmed it using mozilla firefox... it says there my variable LinePath is not declared...

Answer (score 1):

You are making a call to `LinePath` in `AddCoordinate()`, but `LinePath` isn't created until `PlotLine()` is called (by clicking the button).

Perhaps you could create `LinePath` when you declare it, then just call `LinePath.setMap(map);` from `PlotLine()`.

Maybe something like this:

```
<html>

<head>
<link href="https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var Markers = [];
    var Coordinates = [];
    var LinePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path:Coordinates,          
                strokeColor:"#ffffff",
                strokeOpacity:1.0,
                strokeWeight:5
                });


    function initialize()
    {  
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -140.821856);
      var myOptions = {
                zoom: 3,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
          };
      var MarkerSize = new google.maps.Size(48,48);
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    }

    function AddCoordinate( lat, long ) {
      var path = LinePath.getPath(); 
      path.push( new google.maps.LatLng( lat, long ) );
      LinePath.setPath(path);

    }

    function PlotLine()
    {
      LinePath.setMap(map);
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" ></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">AddCoordinate(11,12)</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah... i didn't see that..  :)  now ive already done what you said...i modified it a bit yet im getting the same error..i have appended my question with my modifications... however, it gives me the error: Uncaught TypeError cannot call method 'getPath' of undefined AddCoordinate (anonymous function)  :(

Comment: i found my prob... i confirmed it using mozilla firefox... it says there my variable LinePath is not declared... –

Comment: just came to same conclusion - the AddCoordinate code is running before initalize (which is run when the page has loaded). Changed my answer for what its worth.

Comment: however, it cant be coz i created a global declaration for LinePath

Comment: `LinePath` is null until `initalize()` is run. `initialize()` is run when the page has finsihed loading. `AddCoordinate()` is run before the page has loaded, thus attempting to call an undefined function.

Comment: uh... so meaning to say, what actually happens is AddCoordinate is being called first before initialize?  how come? i didnt know... i thought if i want to initialize values in javascript first before completely loading the page, i will have to use onload()...  well, it appears the other way around... im gonna try it

Comment: correct - `initialize()` is being called when the body has _finished_ loading, `AddCoordinate()` is being called as soon as it is reached - i.e. before the page has loaded.

Comment: ive changed my code and i used $(document).ready(){}. however it appears that they're just the same. Do I have other options? I also tried declaring and instantiating it right away in global declarations but nothing has changed. Im also considering to declare it in the head tag, however it will just be the same thing coz i have to call first the api source before declaring/using anything related to google map.

Comment: Not sure how it fits with the rest of your code, but I've made an example which doesn't seem to error for me.